# How to cancel an event in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, events, visual-c++

I like to cancel an event if there is an error, so the rest of the code won't run.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {if(textBox1->Text == "")//cancel event
}
```

If the text of the textBox1 is empty the event exit so the rest of the code wont run and doesn't create an error.

I do it like this, but is there a better solution to this?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { if(textBox1->Text == "") Error = 1;
if(Error == 0)//Rest of the code);
}
```

Thank you.
Imi007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 'return;'  that would work